# Can't see sub-labels in left-hand menu

Tags: gmail-labels

I have added 3 labels and nested sub-labels within each on the left hand side of my page (underneath my inbox).  I then labelled all my emails.

When I click on the drop-down box next to my label, I can no longer see my choice of sub-labels.

I can see that there are messages filed in the sub-labels when I go to manage labels but cannot I access them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot demonstrating the problem? Be sure you remove any personal information.